# Ember loading wrong devise route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two different devise users(user A and user B) in my application , both have their different sign-in and sign-up routes . When i loaded the same using ember , the user B loaded the user A session . Following are the codes related to both the users .

routes.rb (Rails routing)

```
  devise_for :user A, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "user A/omniauth_callbacks",:registrations => "user A/registrations" , :sessions => "user A/sessions" }

  devise_for :user B
```

router.js (Ember routing)

```
  this.resource('user A', function() {
    this.route('sign_up');
    this.route('sign_in');
  });
  this.resource('user B', function() {
    this.route('sign_up');
    this.route('sign_in');  
  });
```

I understand this might be related to not mentioning the controller for user B in routes.rb and hence ember falls back to the user A session but i might be wrong . Looking forward to some helpful suggestions , as i don't have much experience with ember . More related code will be provided if needed .

Comment: I believe a space is not allowed in routes. Don't know, haven't tried.

Comment: I don't think the issues there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, ember routing may not (necessary) be linked to the actual REST call you make to the server. Ember routing conects all ember componentes (controller, views, templates) and handles what you display on the browser, but you actual server call may be completely different from the route defined in ember. Do you have more code than that in your Ember app?